# How do I get the selected item in a expandable RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development and I started working on an expandable RecyclerView. Now My problem is that my child (sub-modules) list is populated dynamically from the selected parent (Module) on the expandable RecyclerView. I tried using a for loop but only the last child list is populated when I open. I was just wondering if there is a way I could implement an item click listener to just return the single selected module.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ReportAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<ModuleViewHolder, DoiViewHolder> {
Context context;

public ReportAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups, Context context) {
    super(groups);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ModuleViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_module,parent,false);

    return new ModuleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public DoiViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_doi,parent,false);

    return new DoiViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(DoiViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
    ModuleDoi moduleDoi =(ModuleDoi) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

    holder.setDoiName(moduleDoi.getName());

}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(ModuleViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
holder.setModuleName(group.getTitle());

}
```

}

Here is my Parent Holder:

```
public class ModuleViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView moduleName ;

public ModuleViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
moduleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.module_name);


}

  public void  setModuleName(String  name){

    moduleName.setText(name);
 }


 }
```

Here is my Childs holder (Sub Modules)

```
public class DoiViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder  {
TextView doiName;
public DoiViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    doiName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.module_doi_name);

}
public void setDoiName(String name){
    doiName.setText(name);
}

}
```

Here is where I set the adapter. I am using the 
`moduleDoiList = fetchModuleMenus(APPID, MODULENAME);`
  fetch the  submodules list from a json file. the app id in this case is a constant and the MODULENAME is obtained from the Modules Array list.

```
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RESPONSE");
                            moduleDoiList = new ArrayList<>();
                            appModulesList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject eachModuleObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                MODULES modules = new MODULES(eachModuleObject.getString("MODULENAME"),
                                        eachModuleObject.getString("MODULEID"));
                                ModulesList.add(modules);
                                for(int j = 0; j<ModulesList.size(); j++) {
                                    String moduleTitle = ModulesList.get(i).getModuleName();
                                    String MODULENAME = ModulesList.get(i).getModuleName();


                                    moduleDoiList = fetchModuleMenus(APPID, MODULENAME);
                                    appModulesList.add(new AppModules(moduleTitle, moduleDoiList));
                                }
                            }


                            reportAdapter = new ReportAdapter(appModulesList, POIDocsReportsActivity.this);
                            reportAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            rv.setAdapter(reportAdapter);
```

This is my fetchModulesMenu method:

```
  public List<ModuleDoi> fetchModuleMenus(final String appId, final String moduleId) {
    moduleDoiList = new ArrayList<>();
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        boolean error;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(POIDocsReportsActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            });

            String url = AppConfig.SERVER_URL + "load_module_menus.php";
            HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

            hashMap.put("APPID", appId);

            hashMap.put("MODULEID", moduleId);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new JSONObject(hashMap), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        error = jsonObject.getBoolean("ERROR");
                        if (error){
                            Toast.makeText(POIDocsReportsActivity.this, "MENUS NOT FOUND ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("RESPONSE");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject eachMenu = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ModuleDoi moduleDoi = new ModuleDoi(eachMenu.getString("POINAME"), eachMenu.getString("POICODE"));
                                moduleDoiList.add(moduleDoi);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(POIDocsReportsActivity.this, "CONNECTION ERROR ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(POIDocsReportsActivity.this, "NO RESPONSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        }


    };
    thread.run();

   return  moduleDoiList;

   }
```

I am using the [Thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) Custom Expandable Recycler View

Comment: Could you please paste some related code of `click`

Comment: @Ali I have added the code